# Undefined < in app.jsx. using react.js, react router and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I've been having troubles getting my head around react. I've included the app.jsx and webpack files. I keep getting errors with the '<' in the render function in app.jsx. I'm using node express on the server side.

Here is the error:

```
apple$ webpack -w

Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 28ms
   [0] ./app/js/app.jsx 0 bytes [built] [failed]

ERROR in ./app/js/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/apple/Desktop/cs360/myLdsCallings/app/js/app.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react'
| import render from 'react-dom'
| import Route from 'react-router'
```

This is the webpack file

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')


module.exports = {

   devtool: 'inline-source-map',



    entry: "./app/js/app.jsx",
    output: {
        path: "./build",
        filename: "build.js"
    },
    module: { 
    test: /\.jsx?$/, 
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    loader: "babel", 
    query:
      {
        presets:['es2015','react']
      }
}

}
```

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import render from 'react-dom'
import Route from 'react-router'
import IndexRoute from 'react-router'
import Router from 'react-router'
import App from '../components/App'
import Current from '../components/Current'
import Actions from '../components/Actions'
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
import MyActions from '../components/MyActions'
import Without from '../components/Without'
import GlobalNav from '../components/GlobalNav'
import Profile from '../components/Profile'


var routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={App} />
      <Route path='Current' component={Current} />
      <Route path='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path='Actions' component={Actions} />
      <Route path='MyActions' component={MyActions} />
      <Route path='Without' component={Without} />
      <Route path='GlobalNav' component={GlobalNav} />
      <Route path='Profile' component={Profile} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);


ReactDom.render(routes, document.getElementById('content')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had multiple problems with the file:

1. `module` object should have a `loaders` array inside and only there you can specify the loaders.
2. (which you already fixed) The regular expression you were using did not include the `jsx` files but only the `js` files.
3. (fixed as well) With `babel 6` you need to install and specify the presets of the loaders - In your case you are using `es2015` syntax with `jsx`.

**This should be the result of all above fixes:**

```
{ 
    test: /\.jsx?$/,  <--- note that we are testing for jsx and js files.
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    loader: "babel", 
    query:
      {
        presets:['es2015', 'react']
      }
}
```

Don't forget to `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react` and `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: I tried doing that earlier, bug it gave me this instead: ERROR in ./app/js/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/apple/Desktop/cs360/callings/app/js/app.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react'
| import render from 'react-dom'
| import Route from 'react-router'

Comment: @oeste You should add the es2015 loader. see Edit.

Comment: I had added the .jsx? a few minutes ago, but still no effect. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: It's still the error mentioned in my first comment to your answer. I added the error above. Still says Unexpected token at line 1 in app.jsx

Comment: @oeste My last guess is that the loaders should be an array inside of the module object. Like this:
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll try to spend tomorrow looking at that as well. If I get it working I'll post the edit!